# Best location to put dropdown menu items for faster updating, on a database or on visual studio?

Tags: c#, database, dropdown

On a web application (browser-based) using visual studio 2017 and MySQL for Database and IIS for publishing the web app.

Someone ask me to add an item on a dropdown menu, when I search the pool from where can I add an item on a dropdown menu, I've found out that the pool was on the business logic folder on visual studio and not on the database.

My question is, what is the best practice or most efficient when it comes to updating the dropdown list? Is it best to put it on the controller or on the database?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice would be to put all data in SQL and then use the controller to retrieve the data from SQL to put into the View.

Comment: I agree. It is not uncommon that a second application will need access to the same database in the future, and you don't want to have the same list stored in two places!

Answer (score 1):

I think both has its pro's and con's.

If it is in the database,

- you can easily insert a new value that's it. This implies you have access to database and confident in making database changes. Some DBA will have database locked down and any changes will have to go through them.

If it is in the application layer,

- every time you need to add a new value you have to compile and publish to production, which is a lot of steps and things can go wrong when you recompile and publish. If you have a decent CI you are good.
- having it in the application layer also means you do not have to go to the database to fetch it, which means one less database call in your application.
- down the road you may decide that you want to use this same data in a different application, but you won't be able to so, as it is tied only to this application